# как вывести из массива картинку ссылкой?

Tags: php

Есть массив. Как вывести все картинки по адресам media_url ссылками на permalink?

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [media_url] => https://....
                    [permalink] => https://....                                  
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [media_url] => https://....
                    [permalink] => https://....                
                )...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробегаться по массиву в цикле и выводить его элементы:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>   // $data['data'] ???
    <a href="<?= $item['permalink']; ?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?= $item['media_url']; ?>" />
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: не работает и всё тут:( все варианты скобок, кавычек перебрал. не хочет отображаться

Comment: @petrovich что ещё за варианты скобок и кавычек?

Comment: я не могу сделать ссылку из своего массива. не понимаю проблемы и куда копать.
в соседней ветке  человеку предложили ключи брать в такие кавычки echo $keynomerlist["'area'"];
думал, может и мне это поможет, но нет. потом уже сюда написал.

Comment: @petrovich если написать так `<?php foreach ($data as $item):  ?>213 <?php endforeach; ?>` то что выведет?  Кстати, `$data` или `$data['data']`? А как у вас вообще переменная называется?

Comment: моя переменная instPosts. картинки существуют, пути корректные. но ссылки не генерируются никак, ни выводятся картинки.

Comment: @petrovich ну. не знаю как точно вы вставляете текущий код к себе на страницу... надо только вместо `$data` подставить `$instPosts['data']`. Но есть у меня ощущение, что вы его не так вставляете

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Сейчас все заработало, как задумано.

Comment: @petrovich you're welcome %)  Если ответ помог - можно ткнуть на галочку рядом с ответом)

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.
Сегодня у меня трудности с простыми операциями :)